# Wi-fi connection gets "stuck" every hour

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

For some reason,every 30-60 minutes, I experience a loss of Internet connectivity. Wireless still shows connected but I can't open any website (Chrome says "you are offline"). All the messengers also lose connectivity. Windows troubleshooter says it couldn't identify a problem, or sometimes says my DNS server is not accessible. (I use Google's DNS servers.) Switching to a different wireless network instantly fixes the issue, even if the network is on the same router.

My setup is as follows:

Comcast -> ARRIS SURFboard SB6190 -> ASUS AC-RT68U running Merlin firmware -> Netgear A6210 USB wi-fi card

What I've done so far:

- upgraded modem (user to be older surfboard) - no change
- upgraded router (user to be netgear) - no change
- upgraded router firmware to Merlin - no change
- upgraded wireless card (used to have some other AC card) - no change

What am I missing here? Other computers in my house are not getting this. This is definitely not a provider issue, since when I hop onto another network on same modem, the issue goes away. Problem is, I have to do it every half hour, and doing it in the middle of an online game is inconvenient to say the least... Help?

UPDATE: I disabled power management for this adapter (so Windows can't power it down) but that didn't help.

Also, when I'm in the "stuck" state, I can't even ping the router (192.168.1.1). I can ping myself (192.168.1.111) so Winsock and all that stuff are operational.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this so what you have to do is hit your windows key type "device manager" hit enter look for "network adapters" and identify your wireless adapter right-click --> properties --> power management and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but unfortunately it didn't help. I still lost all connectivity while still technically being "on" the wireless network.

Comment: I found out the actual problem with my network adapter it was because my computer starts running out of power somehow and turns off the network adapter. I found this out because my computer crashed and displayed a power error when booted again.